# Using dynamically generated bundle in JSF 1.2

Tags: java, jsf

My webapp requires a `ResourceBundle` that is dynamically created. Is it possible to somehow push it inside `FacesContext` (or anywhere else, for that matter) so that it is later available from a view a la static RB? For example:

```
<h:outputText value="#{myDynaBundle['key.inside.dynamic.rb']}" />
```

By static RB I mean a bundle that is defined inside app-config.xml, such as:

```
<resource-bundle>
    <base-name>messages</base-name>
    <var>msg</var>
</resource-bundle>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class which [`extends ResourceBundle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html) and make it a managed bean.

E.g.

```
public class MyDynaBundle extends ResourceBundle {

    @Override
    protected Object handleGetObject(String key) {
        // Implement bundle value retrieval by key.
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getKeys() {
        // If necessary, implement retrieval of all valid keys.
    }

}
```

which is registered as

```xml
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>myDynaBundle</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.example.MyDynaBundle</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

Comment: Thank you (also meant generally as you saved my a** couple of times).